# I s there any way to extract values separately from the html code shown below

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is for a project I am working on and I want to extract the sales growth of 1 year, 3 years and 5 years separately. I tried doing it using

```py
soap.find("div",{"class":"ratiosingle"}).find_all("span",{"class":"durationvalue"})[1].getText()
```

but the above code is showing an error.

```html
<div class="w-100">
    <div class="ratiosingle">
        <span class="duration">1 Year</span>
        <span class="durationvalue">-27.09%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ratiosingle">
        <span class="duration">3 Year</span>
        <span class="durationvalue">-5.38%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ratiosingle">
        <span class="duration">5 Year</span>
        <span class="durationvalue">1.05%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a = input("Enter symbol of the company\n")
url = "https://ticker.finology.in/company/" + a
print(url)
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
CP = soup.find("div", {"id": "mainContent_clsprice"}).find("span", {"class": "Number"}).getText()
```

Comment: I am using IDEA as the ticker

Comment: url=https://ticker.finology.in/company/RELIANCE
SG=soup.find("div",{"class":"ratiosingle"}).find_all("span",{"class":"duationvalue"})[1].getText()

Comment: The error I am getting is, list index out of range

Comment: it is durationvalue*

Comment: The desired output I want is to display all of the sales growth separately.
sales growth for 1 year i.e. -27.09%
sales growth of 3 years i.e. -5.38%
sales growth of 5 years i.e. 1.05 %

Answer (score 0):

There are several apporaches to get the values, just come up with two of them used ticker IDEA.

**Option#1**
Values as list with `css selectors` and `list comprehension`:

```
[v.text for v in soup.select('#mainContent_divSales span.durationvalue')]

#output
['-6.8%', '14.41%', '3.08%']
```

**Option#2**
More structured with `stripped_strings` as dict:

```
dict([v.stripped_strings for v in soup.select('#mainContent_divSales .ratiosingle')])

#output
{'1 Year': '-6.8%', '3 Year': '14.41%', '5 Year': '3.08%'}
```